# При парсинге JSON (android) неправильно отображаются русские символы

Tags: json, android, get

Есть код ServiceHandler:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by admin on 25.09.2014.
 */
public class ServiceHandler {

    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    public ServiceHandler(){

    }
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method){
        return  this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method, List<NameValuePair> params){
        try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            if(method == POST){
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                if(params!=null){
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            } else if (method == GET){
                if (params!=null){
                    String paramsString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "");
                    url += "?" + paramsString;
                }

                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }

            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
}

MyActitvity.class

public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private static String url = "---//--//--";

    private static final String TAG_TITLE="title";
    private static final String TAG_PICTURE="picture";
    private static final String TAG_HREF="href";
    private static final String TAG_DATE="date";

    JSONArray contacts = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
                String picture = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture)).getText().toString();
                String href = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.href)).getText().toString();
                String date = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date)).getText().toString();

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleContactActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, title);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PICTURE, picture);
                in.putExtra(TAG_HREF, href);
                in.putExtra(TAG_DATE, date);
            }
        });

        new  GetContacts().execute();
    }

private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Идет загрузка ... Ждемс...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response:", ">" + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);

                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String picture = c.getString(TAG_PICTURE);
                    String href = c.getString(TAG_HREF);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

                    HashMap<String, String> neww = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    neww.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                    neww.put(TAG_PICTURE, picture);
                    neww.put(TAG_HREF, href);
                    neww.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                    myList.add(neww);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MyActivity.this, myList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_TITLE, TAG_PICTURE, TAG_HREF, TAG_DATE}, new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.picture, R.id.href, R.id.date});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}

}
```

Подскажите, из-за чего выводит иероглифы. У меня уже мозг кипит. Явно какая-то мелочь, но я ее не вижу =) Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы ответ читаете как? Там при чтении нужно правильную кодировку задать

```
InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
...
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
```

Попробуйте вместо:

```
response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

написать

```
response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "iso-8859-1")
```

Comment: Добавил основной класс. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Alerx, обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло. Только не "iso-8859-1", а "utf-8". =))

Comment: @Alerx, вот и отлично)