# Get json, распознать русские символы

Tags: java, android, json, get

Приведенный ниже код принимает json  с сервера и выводит его в текстовое окно, если на сервере пишу возвращаемое содержимое русскими буквами, то в ответ приходят иероглифы, подскажите пожалуйста, в каком месте и как правильно мне указать кодировку для распознавания символов?
В этом приложении происходит авторизация, после успешной авторизации получаю в ответ слово "Привет", но выводится ?????, как сделать так, чтобы вместо ????? у меня выводилось на экран слово привет?
вот код MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //тут указываем куда будем конектится
            new RequestTask().execute("myurl.com/login1.php");
        }
    });
}

class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       // EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        try {
            //создаем запрос на сервер
            DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
            //он у нас будет посылать post запрос
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            //будем передавать два параметра
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            //передаем параметры из наших текстбоксов
            //логин
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", login.getText().toString()));
            //пароль
          //  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass.getText().toString()));
            //собераем их вместе и посылаем на сервер
            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //получаем ответ от сервера
            String response = hc.execute(postMethod, res);
            //посылаем на вторую активность полученные параметры
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            //то что куда мы будем передавать и что, putExtra(куда, что);
            intent.putExtra(SecondActivity.JsonURL, response);

            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exp=" + e);
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Загружаюсь...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

}

Во второй активити он выводит текст который лежит на сервере

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

public static String JsonURL;
private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myBooks;
private static final String FIRST = "firstname";
public ListView listView;

/** @param result */
public void JSONURL(String result) {

    try {
        //создали читателя json объектов и отдали ему строку - result
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        //дальше находим вход в наш json им является ключевое слово data
        JSONArray urls = json.getJSONArray("data");
        //проходим циклом по всем нашим параметрам
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, Object> hm;
            hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            //читаем что в себе хранит параметр firstname
            hm.put(FIRST, urls.getJSONObject(i).getString("firstName").toString());
            myBooks.add(hm);
            //дальше добавляем полученные параметры в наш адаптер
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SecondActivity.this, myBooks, R.layout.list,
                    new String[] { FIRST, }, new int[] { R.id.text1});
            //выводим в листвбю
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.url);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    myBooks = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    //принимаем параметр который мы послылали в manActivity
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    //превращаем в тип стринг для парсинга
    String json = extras.getString(JsonURL);
    //передаем в метод парсинга
    JSONURL(json);
}
```

}

Comment: А какой масти иероглифы - как они выглядят?

Comment: на любую русскую букву он выдает вопросительный знак в ромбе

Comment: В таком случае сервер отправляет его в кодировке Windows1251 (скорее всего) - что не очень хорошо и желательно исправить на utf-8. Если по каким-то соображениям этого сделать нельзя на стороне сервера, тогда меняйте кодировку при получении - Это где вы отправили запрос на сервер и получаете ваш response. Как именно это сделать зависит от того как вы его получаете - покажете код, подскажем.

Comment: intent.putExtra(SecondActivity.JsonURL, response);

Comment: вот здесь я его получаю, как его обработать?

Comment: String response = hc.execute(postMethod, res);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(SecondActivity.JsonURL, response);

Comment: Код в вопрос и с подробностями: посредством какой сетевой библиотеки этот запрос выполняется и что есть `hc` и аргументы в `execute()`.

Comment: код полностью добавил

Comment: помогите пожалуйста разобраться до конца....

Comment: Как бы HttpClient никто не использует аж с Андроид 4, я даже не застал и вам не советую, но если очень хочется, то тут уже был вопрос с такой проблемой: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/363150/11515  - можете попробовать сделать как там, только кодировку указать правильную. Но лучше познакомьтесь с библиотекой Retrofit - она современная и удовлетворяет большинство потребностей при общении с сервером. В перспективе опыт работы с ней точно пригодится.

Comment: я пытался разобраться с Retrofit, но к сожалению не нашел элементарных примеров, есть только примеры с каким-то серьезным функционалом, а мне бы что-нибудь простенькое, типа того приложения которое написано у меня сейчас.. если вы знаете где такое можно найти, дайте пожалуйста какую-нибудь информацию) и как я понял на сервере для Retrofit нужен некий API который позволяет общаться с сервером, а у меня нет знаний в этой области..( за ответ большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Кодировка нужна чтобы преобразовать массив байтов в строку. Так что она нужна на уровень выше (в месте где ты принимаешь json от сервера). Строчка подаваемая на твой метод уже должна содержать валидные русские буквы в правильной кодировке.

Comment: intent.putExtra(SecondActivity.JsonURL, response);

Comment: response - это то что приходит с сервера, что мне нужно сделать чтобы он не кодировался?